# What does .Er mean in a man page?

Tags: freebsd, manpage

in a man page I'm editing I see the following:

.Er ENOENT ENOENT

what exactly does that mean? I looked in the man(1) man page but don't see anything about how to read the raw files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [HPUX man(5)](http://h20565.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.BINARYPORTLET/public/kb/docDisplay/resource.process/?spf_p.tpst=kbDocDisplay_ws_BI&spf_p.rid_kbDocDisplay=docDisplayResURL&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&spf_p.rst_kbDocDisplay=wsrp-resourceState=docId%253Demr_na-c02261140-2%257CdocLocale%253D&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken):

> .ER *errorname* *punctuation*
>
> - *errorname* is an error name that corresponds
>   to a value assigned to **errno** by a function and described in the ERRORS
>   section of a manpage. It is displayed in roman, enclosed in square
>   brackets. For example, **.ER EIO .** is displayed as [EIO].

Answer (score 3):

For the specifics about `.Er`, see [mdoc(7)](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=mdoc):

The ‘.Er’ errno macro specifies the error return value for section 2, 3,
     and 9 library routines.  The second example below shows ‘.Er’ used with
     the ‘.Bq’ general text domain macro, as it would be used in a section two
     manual page.

```
       Usage: .Er ⟨errno type⟩ ...

                .Er ENOENT      ENOENT
                .Er ENOENT ) ;  ENOENT);
                .Bq Er ENOTDIR  [ENOTDIR]

 The default width is 17n.
```

In general, see [groff_mdoc(7)](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=groff_mdoc&sektion=7) on how to write manual pages.